# Request headers gives TypeError: 'EnvironHeaders' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask

I have this code which doesn't work, and keeps getting me this error:

`TypeError: 'EnvironHeaders' object is not callable`

The Code is:

```
@app.route('/auth', methods=['GET'])
def auth():
    return request.headers.get('x-authorization')
```

As my code explains, am i trying to get the header called: x-authorization, from an incoming request. It is a STS token that is coming in.
Im using flask and importet request from flask

Comment: Could you paste the full code please ? Or atleast the relavant part where you use `EnvironHeaders` ? Also, if `request.headers` is returning a `mapping`, then you need to either use `request.headers.get('x-authorization')` or `request.headers['x-authorization']`

Comment: Right now, im testing. So i just want to print out the header on 127.0.0.1:5000/auth
But that's the only thing i got atm

Comment: Why don't you print headers, and see what you are getting? Then see if it's even there.

Comment: There's still nothing there. Same error. Object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

Headers in flask, request.headers.get is a dictionary. Hence it is supposed to be accessed as `request.headers['x-authorization']`

Using curly braces makes it a function call like `foo()`.
You need to use  `[]` instead of `()`